# Android Studio accuses Google Repository is not installed in the SDK Manager

Tags: android, google-maps, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I am trying to add Google Maps on my Android project and I was following this instructions:
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

However, when I try to add

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'`

to my `build.gradle`, AndroidStudio says

```
Dependency on Play Services, but the SDK installation does not have the "Extras > Google Repositories" installed. Open the SDK Manager and install it.
```

The problem is that I have it installed already:
[image: sdk manager]

I have already checked on File > Project Structure > Android SDK location and I am using the correct SDK path.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens that I was trying to add the dependency to the top-level build.gradle, where it somehow said I needed the Google Repository.

I added the code to the "inner" (application) build.gradle and it still did not work. I had to set my minimum SDK to 10 (instead of 8), so it worked.

Silly mistake, and it took me hours to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Android Studio and Android SDK manager. In my case Google Repository didn't show up in the list, so after searching a bit i ended up reinstalling Android Studio, and it worked.

I recommend you to wait a bit, maybe someone can provide a simpler solution. 
If you can't wait, just reinstall Android Studio. A clean updated installation should fix the problem.

Comment: I had this issue as well (Google Repository didn't show up in SDK Manager's list), and I just updated everything and restarted the SDK Manager. I'll try to reinstall Android Studio. Thanks for your reply

Comment: I downloaded the new Android Studio version v0.8.0 (mine was 0.5.2), I deleted and downloaded Google Repository again, but the problem persists.